Trying to access array offset on value of type null on laravel
I am encountering an error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" when attempting to send a password reset email using Mailtrap in my Laravel application. This error occurs when the application tries to access an array offset or object property that is null.
.env code
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=5bbd4ea216db1c
MAIL_PASSWORD=********8e96
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="admin@school.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

forgot password mail code
class ForgotPasswordMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Forgot Password ',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'email.forgot',
            with: [
                'user' => $this->user,
            ],
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}


controller code
public function postForgotPassword(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::getEmailSingle($request->email);

        if (!empty($user)) {
            $user->remember_token == Str::random(30);
            $user->save();
            mail::to($user->email)->send(new ForgotPasswordMail($user));
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', "Please check your email and reset your password");

        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Email not found in the system");
        }

    }

view file
@component('mail::message')
Hello{{$user->name}},
<p>We understand it happens</p>

@component('mail::button', ['url' => url('reset/', $user->remember_token)])
Reset your Password
@endcomponent
<p> In case you have any issues recovering your password,please contact us.</p>
Thanks,<br>
{{config('app.name')}}
@endcomponent 

check through and help identify the issue....
I have tried to find the null value and I dont seem to find it
C:\Users\USER\sample-demo\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\Smtp\Stream\AbstractStream.php :92
            }
            if ($metas['eof']) {
                throw new TransportException(sprintf('Connection to "%s" has been closed unexpectedly.', $this->getReadConnectionDescription()));
            }
            if (false === $line) {
                throw new TransportException(sprintf('Unable to read from connection to "%s": ', $this->getReadConnectionDescription()).error_get_last()['message']);
            }
        }
 
        $this->debug .= sprintf('[%s] < %s', date('c'), $line);
 
        return $line;
    }
 
    public function getDebug(): string
    {
        $debug = $this->debug;


Please add the full stack trace of the error so we know where the error originated from

hello... please check again i have added the full stack

error_get_last() is returning null, which is odd. You can try submitting a bug to Symfony to figure that out. However, your real issue is Unable to read from connection to..., which makes it sound like it can't connect to sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
